# Is ConTeXt compatible with the memoir class?

Tags: memoir, context, incompatibility

Is ConTeXt compatible with the `memoir` class?

Comment: ConTeXt is not syntax compatible with memoir, as lockstep has already mentioned. However, it is _feature_ compatible: anything that you do using memoir is also possible using ConTeXt...although, you will have to use a different syntax. (IMO ConTeXt's consistent and key-value driven syntax is its main advantage over LaTeX)

Answer (score 13):

No. `memoir` is a document class written for the LaTeX format (more precisely, for its version 2e). The first code lines of `memoir` read:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{memoir}%
  [2011/03/06 v3.6j configurable book, report, article document class]
```